# problem using Arduino serial in conjunction with python

Tags: python, arduino, serial-port, arduino-uno

I'm attempting to let my python code read from my arduino serial connection, and i get this error message.

```
File "C:\Users\IRONSERVITOR\PycharmProjects\More pygame 23\11\22\venv\lib\site-packages\serial\serialwin32.py", line 64, in open
    raise SerialException("could not open port {!r}: {!r}".format(self.portstr, ctypes.WinError()))
serial.serialutil.SerialException: could not open port 'COM4': PermissionError(13, 'Access is denied.', None, 5)
```

My arduino code:

```
#include <ezButton.h>

#define VRX_PIN  A0 // Arduino pin connected to VRX pin
#define VRY_PIN  A1 // Arduino pin connected to VRY pin
#define SW_PIN   2  // Arduino pin connected to SW  pin

ezButton button(SW_PIN);

int xVal = 0; // To store value of the X axis
int yVal = 0; // To store value of the Y axis
int bVal = 0; // To store value of the button

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600) ;
  button.setDebounceTime(50); // set debounce time to 50 milliseconds
}

void loop() {

  // reading the analog X and Y analog values
  xVal = analogRead(VRX_PIN);
  yVal = analogRead(VRY_PIN);

  // Read the button value
  bVal = button.getState();


  // print data to Serial
  if (xVal == 1023){
    Serial.println(" ");
    Serial.print('1');
    delay(100);
  }

  if (xVal == 0){
    Serial.println(" ");
    Serial.print("2");
    delay(100);
  }

  if (yVal == 1023){
    Serial.println(" ");
    Serial.print("down ");
  }

  if (yVal == 0){
    Serial.println(" ");
    Serial.print("up ");
  }

  if (bVal == 0){
    Serial.println(" ");
    Serial.print("hide ");
  }

}
```

My python code

```
import serial


ard = serial.Serial(port='COM4', baudrate=9600, timeout=0.1)

while True:
    command = ard.read()
    if command:
        ard.flushInput()
        if str(command) == '1':
            print('right')
        elif str(command) == '2':
            print('left')
ard.close()
```

Each piece of code works on its own, i only have issues when i use them at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Issue was having the if command == 1, the correct version is if  command == b'1':